# Find files changed/not changed since they were added in subversion

Tags: svn

I have a bunch of files in a subversion repository. Most of the times, we keep adding new files to the repository without changing them later. However, we may edit some files after they were added.

I need to find out which files have not been changed since they got added to the repository and which ones have been changed since they were added.

Is it possible to do this without a non-trivial script or running 'svn log' for each file?

Answer (score 0):

```
svn log -v > svn.log
grep "^ *A " svn.log | cut -d " " -f 5 | gsort -u > added.lst
grep "^ *M " svn.log | cut -d " " -f 5 | gsort -u > modified.lst
comm -2 -3 added.lst modified.lst > only-added.lst
```

where gsort is GNU sort.